# Diagonal border on one side of a div

Tags: html, css, background, border, diagonal

[Click for the problem's illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2BNb.png)

How should I implement this, given the fact that the background is not solid? I was trying different solutions, but none of them fully fit

Comment: How ?' many ways ... use border-values to make the diagonal --- use a pseudo-element to fake the diagonal .... skew transform a bg element .... Try something and show us the code you try

Answer (score 3):

Start like this,

```
<div id="box">
   <div id="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

#rectangle { 
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 100px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 300px solid white;
}
```